# Storing php query result into an array

Tags: entities

How can I store php query result into an array in Computed field code(PHP)?

For example:

```
$query = db_query('SELECT field_holiday_date_value FROM field_data_field_holiday_date');
```

how can I store it into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

This will store the records in $result as an array. You then need to store it in the computed field, which is something like this:

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $result;
```

References:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7

https://drupal.org/node/126522

Comment: is $result an array?

Comment: Yes, just as I said. If you read the documentation in the first link and read the first comment, you can see what ->fetchAll does.

Comment: But when I tried to use it like this

if(in_array($curr2,$result))

it did not get what I wanted to output.

Comment: You asked a clear question and I gave the clear answer. Let's keep it this way for future people looking for the same thing. Now you're asking a different question with a different problem. If you want that answered you should make a new question and give specific examples of what data you are working with and what you are trying to achieve. This isn't a forum for helping people, it's a question and answer website. If you want a specific answer you need to ask that question.

Comment: I just thought that if it was saved as an array, I can access it using in_array. 


FYI.Im not asking another question in my comment. I just SAID(not ASK) what was the output so that other people will know the output :)

thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: No problem. The array that is output is an associative array of standard PHP objects, as described in the documentation in the first link. `in_array` would only work if you were searching for that PHP object, which I suspect you are not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743527/how-does-in-array-check-if-an-object-is-in-an-array-of-objects